# Laravel 8: Missing required parameter for [Route: edit.question] [URI: editquestion/{question}] [Missing parameter: question]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum project and in this project, I want to make an `editquestion` page that users can edit their questions.

So here is a button on blade that redirects user to that edit page:

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question', $show->slug) }}">
   <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Edit Question</button>
</form>
```

And this is the route for showing the `editquestion` blade:

```
Route::get('editquestion/{question:slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'editQuestion'])->name('edit.question');
```

And this is the Controller method `editQuestion()` which returns a blade:

```
public function editQuestion(Question $slug)
    {
        return view('questions.editquestion',[
            'slug' => $slug
        ]);
    }
```

But now, whenever I click on `Edit Question`, I get this error:

**Missing required parameter for [Route: edit.question] [URI: editquestion/{question}] [Missing parameter: question]**

So what is going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share your idea or suggestion about this...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:**

I added input hidden of `slug`:

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ $show->slug }}" />
   <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Edit Question</button>
</form>
```

And get this error:

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: edit.question] [URI: editquestion/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug]. (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\gooyanet\root\resources\views\questions\question.blade.php)
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Here is `web.php` routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::get('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::resource('profile' , ProfileController::class);
    Route::get('ask' , [QuestionController::class, 'showForm'])->name('ask');
    Route::post('ask' , [QuestionController::class, 'postForm']);
    Route::get('questions/{slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'showQuestion']);
    Route::post('questions/{question}/answer' , [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
    Route::get('answers/{ans}' , [QuestionController::class, 'editAnswer'])->name('edit.answer');
    Route::get('editquestion/{slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'editQuestion'])->name('edit.question');
    Route::post('editquestion/{id}' , [QuestionController::class, 'updateQuestion'])->name('update.question');
    Route::post('questions/{ans}' , [QuestionController::class, 'updateAnswer'])->name('update.answer');
    Route::delete('questions/{ans}' , [QuestionController::class, 'destroyAnswer'])->name('destroy.answer');
    Route::delete('{id}' , [QuestionController::class, 'destroyQuestion'])->name('destroy.question');
});
```

Comment: Try to use slug only in route as Route::get('editquestion/{slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'editQuestion'])->name('edit.question');

Comment: @IrshadKhan Now I get **404 not found** message. Even I added `dd($slug);` to the method controller, but still shows 404 page

Comment: run php artisan route:cache

Comment: @IrshadKhan 404 not found page still apears

Comment: Set your form action as action="{{ route('edit.question', ['slug' => $show->slug]) }}"

Comment: @IrshadKhan Nope! Still get the issue :(

Comment: Now you can set hidden field in form with id and get id in request parameter so you no need to send id in form action. its work

Comment: @IrshadKhan Do I need to add method of POST in order to do that?

Comment: yeah you set post method

Comment: this time you are geeting question data or updating it ?

Comment: @IrshadKhan I just added an UPDATE #1 to post about your suggestion,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229760/discussion-between-tejoslaeslio-and-irshad-khan).

Comment: Step 1 when you have a problem: check the docs.  Googling "Laravel named routes" takes me to the relevant docs, which clearly show the syntax for [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes): `route('edit.question', ['slug' => $show->slug])`.  Step 2: check your routes - that route is a `get` route, but your form is `post`. BTW in one of your routes you show `{question:slug}`, which should probably just be `{slug}`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I tried it with hyperlink instead of form `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('edit.question', ['slug' => $show->slug]) }}">Edit Question</a>` and it says `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: So clearly the get route you've shown us is either not in place, or is being overridden by another route ... try commenting out all other routes except it, if it works, you have a conflict with another route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

```
public function editQuestion(Question $slug)
    {
        return view('questions.editquestion',[
            'slug' => $slug
        ]);
    }
```

you are injecting `Question model` in *editQuestion(Route-model binding)*, so you should pass your question class instance in your form too.

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question', $show) }}">
   <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Edit Question</button>
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question', ['question' => $show]) }}">
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `slug` parameter to the route function

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question', ['slug' => $show->slug]) }}">
```

Comment: Awesome the key for me was the the second parameter in the route command must be an *array* with all the possible models that are bound to the route. I just added additional parameters and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem notice is incorrect syntax in Blade (options parameters should be an array in the route() function with parameter key name same as you define it in route declaration) : 
Change this :

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question', $show->slug) }}">
```

to this :

```
<form action="{{ route('edit.question', ['question' => $show->slug]) }}">
```

The other thing I think is incorrect syntax also in routing (route parameter should be only one key word, you have to choose beetween "question" or "slug", not both separated with dots) :

```
Route::get('editquestion/{question}' , [QuestionController::class, 'editQuestion'])->name('edit.question');
```

If you want to make this route parameter optional see : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Also, i don't know what your object **$show->slug** contain, but you should check it with a dump.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it happens because you haven't set the primary key and auto-increment. Please check the database and confirm your primary key column is not null.